# parsing complex json object

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, gson

Hi I am trying to parse json object below. But the problem is, inside the ***profile*** attribute, there is an attribute called ***fields*** which is sometimes a json object and sometime an json-array, so it is creating a problem when i am trying to use Gson to parse it. I followed this link but it didn't help [How to dynamically handle json response array/object using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373417/how-to-dynamically-handle-json-response-array-object-using-gson) , so help is needed from someone who encountered this before, thanks!.

```
{
  "users": {
    "profile": [
      {
        "fields": {
          "key": "fname",
          "value": "Michael"
        }        
      },
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "key": "lname",
            "value": "Bob"
          },
          {
            "key": "age",
            "value": "25"
          }

        ]
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify this: You parse the JSON object with Google gson, or do you need this solution for some other language?

Comment: Hi Philipp, what i what is to convert this json to pojo java class so that i can retrieve any field. I am working in java by the way.

Comment: Sounds like poor JSON creatoin logic if you have a case where multiple "fields" gives you an array on JSON encoding and s single field value gives you an object. Typically one would expect to use an array in all cases (whether the array has multiple values, a single value, or no values). Do you have control over the initial JSON serialization?

Comment: _"I followed this link but it didn't help How to dynamically handle json response array/object using Gson"_ I think it should help. Write a custom deserializer.

Comment: @mike brant, no i don't have control over it. I am getting as a response from calling external web service.

Comment: What happened when you tried the solution in the link?  The solution there looks right to me.

Comment: @AlexisC. Can you please try to give the skeleton of the pojo class with respect to this json.

Comment: @user3780757 Your pojo could contains a list of objects. The thing that matters is that you need to implement the deserialization process yourself with a custom deserializer.

Comment: @MikeBrant, Here are the two pojo classes i am using 
 public class Field {

    private String key;
    private String Value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return Value;
    }

    public void setContent(String Value) {
        this.Value = Value;
    }

}

public class profile {

 private Field fields;


 public fields getFields() {
     return attribute;
 }

 public void setFields(Field field) {
     this.field = field;
 }

}

Comment: @AlexisC. so it seems that is what i missing. Can you give me a hint on that? I am only trying to replicate what i got from the link.

Comment: Show your deserializer

Comment: @AlexisC. i am using as follows:  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(
     new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();
   Users response;
   response = gson
     .fromJson(jsonInString, Users.class);