# gson parse object when there is data and array when no data

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I use retrofit2 + gson.
My question is about when server has data it send me json like:

```
{
 "next":false,
 "total":4,
 "start":0,
 "rows":[
  {
     "calls":29,
     "new_calls":29,
     "new_quality_calls":10,
     "item":"MzY4NzA3NDA0Mw",
     "sessions":3,
     "calls_per":966.66666666666663
  },
  {
     "calls":15,
     "new_calls":15,
     "new_quality_calls":5,
     "item":"test312312312",
     "sessions":2,
     "calls_per":750
  },
  {
     "calls":0,
     "new_calls":0,
     "new_quality_calls":0,
     "item":"test",
     "sessions":4,
     "calls_per":0
  },
  {
     "calls":0,
     "new_calls":0,
     "new_quality_calls":0,
     "item":"test2",
     "sessions":2,
     "calls_per":0
  }
],
"summary":{
  "sessions":11,
  "calls":44,
  "new_calls":44,
  "new_quality_calls":15,
  "calls_per":400
}
}
```

But when there is no data, it send me:

```
{"next":false,"total":0,"start":0,"rows":[],"summary":[]}
```

The problem is that `summary` is an object or array is some case.
i use this site to make gson calsses http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

When i got data its ok, but when there is no data i got an error:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 56 path
```

How to solve it automatically by retroft2 `(.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()))` without manual data parsing?

Comment: You can use HashMap for this problem.

Comment: @kunwar97 show me please how?

Comment: Sorry, hashmap will not solve your problem. You need to create custom deserializer. Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579839/android-parse-json-response-when-a-key-can-be-a-json-object-or-a-json-array?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Add your own converter which will parse AST (`readTree`), check `$.summary` type, fix it, and then give this fixed AST to TypeAdapter.